# Continuous function and connected component

Tags: general-topology

Let $X$ be a completely regular topological space and $C$ a connected component of $X$ such that $C\not= X$. Is there a real valued continuous function $f$ over $X$ such that  $f(C)\not=\{0\}$ and $f(X-C)=\{0\} $ ?

Comment: What is the origin of your question? Are you sure it is correctly stated?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Such function does not have to exist.

Take $X=\mathbb{Q}$ with the standard topology, take $C=\{1\}$, which is a connected component since $\mathbb{Q}$ is totally disconnected. Note that you are asking whether there is a continuous function $f:\mathbb{Q}\to\mathbb{R}$ such that $f(x)=0$ everywhere except $x=1$. This clearly cannot happen.

Your statement is true however if you assume that $C$ is clopen. Being completely regular is irrelevant.